# How to Customize AppCompat Material Button Style?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am using the AppCompat theme and I want set the minHeight attribute on my buttons:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="...?">
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>
</style>
```

However, there is no `Widget.AppCompat.Button` style to set as the parent for `MyButtonStyle`. If I use `android:Widget.Button`, then all my buttons look like the old crappy style. I tried various other AppCompat themes like `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button`, but they do not work.

Leaving out a parent theme for the button style also causes the button not to be styled correctly.

How can I customize the default `Theme.AppCompat` `buttonStyle`?

Comment: They've now added a button in as well: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have `Base.MyButtonStyle` extend `android:Widget.Holo.Button` on API 14+ (in `res/values-v14/styles.xml`) and `android:Widget.Material.Button` on API 21+ (in `res/values-v21/styles.xml`. This style will change according to the device system version. Put your platform specific modifications here.

Then have `MyButtonStyle` extend `Base.MyButtonStyle` and define the `android:minHeight` here (in `res/values/styles.xml`). This will apply to all platforms.

You buttons then can use style `MyButtonStyle`.

This example assumes your minimum SDK is 14.

And yes, there's no appcompat-v7 button style (well, at least not yet).

**EDIT**

This assumes you're OK with Holo button on platforms older than Lollipop. It feels unobtrusive and if you can do without ripples, it should be just fine. If you want ripples I suggest you google for a third party lollipop button library.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I was thinking setting the button theme to Holo wouldn't work right on 15-20 for some reason, but of course it does and produces the desired outcome.

Answer (score 5):

Custom Button Style With AppCompat +22 
in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Button.Tinted" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">YOUR_TINT_COLOR</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item> </style>
```

in your layout.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/but_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/but_continue"
        android:theme="@style/Button.Tinted" />
```

Comment: This was my approach until I noticed that disabled buttons looked just like enabled ones

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question, it appears [AppCompat does not in fact support](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) the `Button` widget presently:

> AppCompat provides similar behaviour on earlier versions of Android
>   for a subset of UI widgets:
>
> - Everything provided by AppCompat’s toolbar (action modes, etc)
> - EditText
> - Spinner
> - CheckBox
> - RadioButton
> - Switch (use the new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat)
> - CheckedTextView

The only workaround I see would be to recreate the Material button style from the Android source code, a task which extends outside the scope of my desire.

Comment: It support it now for 22.1.0

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'  in build.gradle in Android Studio seems to fail getting the package. How should I include the v22?

Comment: The latest version of appcompat does indeed have a button: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

Answer (score 2):

With new **MaterialComponent** it is convenient to use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` instead of regular `Button`.

But to style it, there is used the different attribute in the theme 
 - `materialButtonStyle`, with this parent theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`.

Then the theme should look like this:

```
<style name="NewAppTheme" 
       parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    .......
    <-- IMPORTANT if you are using com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton to style them use this parameter
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in `ButtonStyle` you can change button attributes like this:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:`

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32363833