# Widget.AppCompat.Button colorButtonNormal shows gray

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have `values:styles.xml` with:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and `values-v21:styles.xml` with:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
      <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And app style with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
</style>
```

But the colors appears grey instead of `@color/my_color`

Comment: You should accept an answer so other people know which solution worked.

Comment: @Ben You are right

Comment: There is no answer...

Comment: I believe I have tried all the below answers (in Android Studio 3.4 designer, API 28), with no success: with/without Android prefix; style/theme; button theme & global theme (applied to button). All cases either produce unstyled-grey or styled-accent (never my chosen color).

Answer (score 59):

To customize one Button only set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"` to your Button.

```
<Button
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
    />
```

Define your style as you did in your question

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

[EDIT]

See GitHub demo [here](https://github.com/AlexanderTolstykh/MaterialButtonPreLollipop)

Comment: yeah but I want to set the color of the button

Comment: @danielgomezrico just define 'colorButtonNormal' inside 'AppTheme.Button' as you did in your question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @danielgomezrico It works for me. I am using appcompat v7:22.2.0. What version of appCompat are you using?
(But it works for me as well with 22.1.1).
Try to use this without overriding buttonStyle in your main theme, if you do that.

Comment: @danielgomezrico I Created demo and published it on GitHub. See my update to answer

Comment: I was doing style=.. instead of android:theme=... Thanks!

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.tec.., but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper getting this exception when apply it style as theme

Comment: I used android:onClick="dtmfOnClick" attribute.. I think exception getting because of this. But that method is there in activity and for other buttons it is working fine. When apply theme to button I am getting this exception

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar, try to remove android:onClick attribute in xml. If problem really with this parameter, then define click listener in code using setOnClickListener(...). But this problem sounds really weird. When I have time I will try to check it as well.

Comment: `android:theme` doesn't work: a button lost its border and bg (API 23, Design lib 23.2.1)

Comment: @konopko, I use supportLibraryVersion 23.3.0 and it works fine.

Comment: For this to work, you will need to remove the `<item name="android:buttonStyle">` section from your AppTheme `<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: why does it work with android:theme, and not with android:style? Isn't theme for using a style on childeren?

Answer (score 51):

Use `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` as a parent for your style.

```
<style name="RedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Use `android:theme`, not `style` in buttons definitions:

```
<Button android:theme="@style/RedButton"/>
```

See [AppCompat v21 > Theming](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and [Android Support Library v22.1 - AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) blog posts.
(note on second post, `android:theme` is supported on API11-, it just doesn't do automatic inheritance from parent, you will have to specify it on each child, not an issue here but worth mentioning - see [Chris Banes'](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) post on that).

Comment: Why `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` ?

Comment: @valentin +1 for android:theme

Comment: if this still doesn't work for you, especially when using support dialogfragment in android 5 or above, try prefixing colorButtonNormal with android. That is: `android:colorButtonNormal`

Answer (score 14):

Put the xml line below in your "AppTheme" xml, rather than trying to set it from the "AppTheme.Button". This works for me on v22.1.1 with non-lollipop devices. I'm guessing this is a bug because your solution above works fine for lollipop.

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
```

Answer (score 14):

Ensure your `Activity` is extending `AppCompatActivity`, otherwise it won't handle appCompat styles properly.

- class: `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`
- Gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
</style>
```

remove the `android:`

Answer (score 9):

That works:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- android:buttonStyle for v21+ and buttonStyle for the rest -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
</style>
```

`colorButtonNormal` can be set in the theme style. To change the text color, size or any other feature of the button you can create a style and then using `buttonStyle` (less than v21) or `android:buttonStyle` (v21+) in the the theme style to set the button style.

Answer (score 3):

v21/styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme.BlueButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_white</item>
    </style>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.BlueButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue_tint</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_white</item>
</style>
```

Initially I'm too facing this problem. After making correction like above I got correct UI button

Comment: And you set `android:buttonStyle` too or how do you set the stlyle to the button?

Comment: I used this --> android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BlueButton'"

Comment: but the question is about using `android:buttonStyle` but thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug on Android framework that we can not change customize `colorButtonNormal` with `Widget.AppCompat.Button` theme.
A workaround solution is to define another custom `AppCompat` theme and use `colorAccent` to set `colorButtonNormal`.

There are two following steps.
1.Define another theme for your custom button.

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Custom button theme. -->
  <style name="CustomButtonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Set your desired button color here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

2.Apply button theme in layout.

```
<Button android:theme="@style/CustomButtonTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think the parent widget you used might be not correct one, it should `android:Widget.Button` for API version 21 or earlier version, for later version 21 or above you should use `android:Widget.Material.Button. Let say you have default style should look see below.

```
res/values/styles.xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/my_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

For API version 21 the resource style file should look like (res/values-v21/style.xml)

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/my_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Thank you Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: But `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button`don´t do that for me (the Material/Compat check)?

Comment: Just use Button Widget. It automatically works on pre-Lollipop if you use AppCompat theme. At least that's what official document says.

Comment: Can you post the link for it please?

Answer (score 1):

In case you wonder why `colorButtonNormal` is not picked up as defined for disabled buttons, you might also need to set `android:disabledAlpha` to `1.0` in your theme, otherwise your color will by default blend into the button's background. Example:

```
<style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">1.0</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_solid_disabled_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_solid_accent_color</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/my_button_style</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try buttonStyle instead of android:buttonStyle, since this is AppCompat attribute pre Lollipop, so it should be without android prefix