# Themed Button onClick force closes app

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

This is my XML Code for Button element, with theme:

**splashscreen.xml**

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Here →"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="sendMain"
        android:id="@+id/button2"  
        android:theme="@style/SomeButtonStyle2"    
        />
```

***onClick()* at SplashScreen.java**

```
 public void sendMain(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

This gives a dialog box saying "The App has stopped" and the app force closes.

**logcat**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMain(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'
```

But, when the `android:theme="@style/SomeButtonStyle2"` is **removed**, app works **fine**, and I can move to next activity with button onclick.

*SomeButtonStyle2* at **styles.xml**

```
<style name="SomeButtonStyle2" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">

        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/myown</item>

    </style>
```

*myown* color at **colors.xml**

```
<color name="myown">#1E88E5</color>
```

**What I want:**

A colored button which takes me to next activity onclick.

*Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: please post the theme code for SomeButtonStyle2

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add. Edited now. Have a look :)

Comment: Useful article to understand theme vs style: https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TouchBoarder, Yes, your answer works too. But couldn't change the color. 
Found a solution to use android:theme and get it working too. If android:onclick is removed from xml, and used in Java programatically, **android:theme** can be used :)

**splashscreen.xml** [With android:theme but android:onclick removed]

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Here →"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"       
    android:id="@+id/button2"  
    android:theme="@style/SomeButtonStyle2"    
    />
```

**SplashScreen.java** [With onClickListener]

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
            }
        });
```

So, to summarize, using `OnClickListener` instead of `onClick()` in **xml** works with `android:theme`. Thank you guys for all your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `android:theme` with `style`

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Here →"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="sendMain"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/SomeButtonStyle2"
        />
```

If you want a material colored button you could try this AppCompat style and tint it with your own color:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/your_custom_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Here →"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:onClick="sendMain"
    android:id="@+id/button2"/>
```

Comment: Did it now. Button works. But the style isn't applied. Button doesn't look like a Material design button.

Comment: Try to set the parent of the style to AppCompatButton

Comment: I just get the Gray button, no coloring. But activity works, anyway to color App Compat buttons?

Comment: Add material theme to the manifest of your activity. That'll do

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Below is the style I used, works like a charm! Thanks a ton! :)

`<style name="SomeButtonStyle2" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">

        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/myowndaw</item>

    </style>`

Comment: @ReazMurshed Got it working already. But anyway wanna know, How do I add material theme to the manifest?

Comment: In your manifest put ... `<activity
            android:name=".Activities.NewActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>`
And in your styles.xml add the theme like this - `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`

Comment: @TouchBoarder Can you exactly mention the style to AppCompatButton? Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored gives only Green color tho I mention something else. Sorry for being noob.

Comment: @TouchBoarder Can you help me? It doesn't work. Only Green Color appears. Same prob here too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860906/widget-appcompat-button-colorbuttonnormal-shows-gray)

Comment: @AnirudhKarthik see updated answer, you can set the tint to your own color with `app:backgroundTint="@color/your_custom_color"`

Comment: @AnirudhKarthik this will not display a raised button with ripple effects on pre lollipop, for that you need to use a 3rd party library like https://github.com/rey5137/material

Comment: @TouchBoarder Yeah, I don't need a ripple effect. Your edited answer is good, material button, moves to activity. But the color of the button always remains green no matter what I change the backgroundTint. If the color of this could be changed, everything's fine, sorry for disturbing. TIA.

Comment: Strange, it' should change color as long as you don't override the BG color again somewhere. Anyway please accept the answer if it solved your question;)

Comment: @TouchBoarder Got the solution, check out the answer which I've posted. Thanks for your answer, it too helped.