# AppCompat Theme doesn't apply on Button when Debugging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Recently I changed my Xamarin android project to use an AppCompat Theme, now I wanted to apply a custom color to my Buttons. The strange problem I have is that the color is applied in the designer, but when I debug my Application my Buttons are always gray as if I don't apply anything.

I define my theme in my AndroidManifest.XML with:

```
  <application android:label="MyApp" 
  android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></application>
```

And my theme in my values/styles.xml

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">#005B86</item>
  <item name="colorControlNormal">#005B86</item> 
  </style>
```

I also tried it with this code:

```
  <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="MyTheme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_normal</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonThemeColored" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
  <item name="colorButtonNormal">#2196F3</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
  </style>
```

I tried to apply my styles.xml as styles and as theme to my buttons, but both works only in the Designer, but not when really debugging the app.

My Activity is defined like this:

```
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

I know there are various examples out there, but I feel like I have tried everything and nothing works really well.

### Update

My Buttons look like this in the designer, but in debugging they are grey. Please click it to have a better view. (Sorry for bad image)

[image: In my designer my buttons look like this]

Comment: what do you mean by custom color to your buttons ??

Comment: I added a picture of how my buttons look in the designer. When debugging they are only grey, not blue.

Comment: you need to change background color android:background="@color/Your_Color"

Comment: This didn't work either. I think about creating the project from start on with AppCompat, could it be a problem with the cache or something?

Comment: set background directly to your view (in this case your button )  remove style , there are no cache

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34517103/7790901

Comment: @Alexandre your answer helped me a lot, thx. Would like to add it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Nick77 You're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like the example alexandre commented.

[Widget.AppCompat.Button colorButtonNormal shows gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860906/widget-appcompat-button-colorbuttonnormal-shows-gray/34517103#34517103)

I used the answer with highest rep and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

first create xml file --> under values folder with name Colors.xml

set your color inside it 
// color name           // color hex value

```
<color name="bluey_grey">#a5b9c2</color>
```

// apply background to your button

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/bluey_grey"/>
```

hope this help

Comment: Thx for your comment, I have wanted to done it like in the example alexandre commented it :)